# How to create chrome tab of develop Chrome Extension like window.location?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome extension.
I have a requiremen that is create a new tab with some params like javascript 'window' function.

By default javascript window function, i need to set this code as below then `window.location.replace` allow permission to access the page in new window.

```
window.name = JSON.stringify({
    id : 'tmp',
    companyCode : companyCode,
    locationCode : locationCode,
    terminalNo : terminalNo,
    terminalKey : terminalKey,

    server:{ 
        protocol : protocol,
        remoteHost : remoteHost,
        remotePort : remotePort,

        clientHost : clientHost,
        localPort : clientPort,
        webContext : null,

        gcRemoteHost : remoteHost,
        gcRemotePort : remotePort,

        soaPort: 9091,
        webSocketPort : 9099,
    } 
});
```

Now, I am using the google chrome api to create tab.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
   url: new_location
});
```

So, I have a question, How should I pass above `window.name` to create a new tab that I can access the new location.

Comment: The new_location is web url,  it need to receive exactly window.name value before allow to me access the website. Is it possible to simulate window.name when create a chrome tab

Comment: Related: [Pass a parameter to a content script injected using chrome.tabs.executeScript()](//stackoverflow.com/q/17567624)

Answer (score 1):

Inject a content script code that sets the name.

1. Permit the URL (better) or `"<all_urls>"` (worse, but sometimes unavoidable) in manifest.json:

   ```
   "permissions": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
   ```
2. Put the name into a variable:

   ```
   var windowName = JSON.stringify({
       foo: 'bar',
   });
   ```
3. Use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) in a background/popup/options page script to run the content script code as a string with embedded window name as a parameter in the newly created tab:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create({
       url: 'http://www.example.com'
   }, function(tab) {
       runContentCode(tab.id, injectedSetWindowName, windowName);
   });

   function injectedSetWindowName(name) {
       window.name = name;
   }

   function runContentCode(tabId, fn, params) {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
           code: '(' + fn + ')(' + JSON.stringify(params) + ')',
           runAt: 'document_start',
       });
   }
   ```

In case you already have an automatically executed content script (e.g. declared in manifest.json), use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) (chrome.tabs.[sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)) to send the window name and set it accordingly.