# Content script code is not being executed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've taken a look at other related SO posts and the solutions haven't helped solve my issue. This is my first chrome extension, so please bear with me!

I'm writing a simple chrome extension that searches for user provided keywords on a webpage. I can't get the content script that returns the DOM content to run. Some of the code, I've taken from an answer in another SO post, but I can't seem to get it to work for me.

I put a console.log("hello world") at the top of the file, and it doesn't show up, so I think it might be the structure of my project.

**manifest.json**

```js
{
    "name": "keyword search",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [ "tabs" , "storage", "activeTab", "<all_urls>"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "html/form.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "js": [ "js/jquery.min.js", "content_scripts/content_script.js" ]
    }],
    "homepage_url": "http://google.com/"
}
```

**js/popup.js**

```js
function run() {
    running = true;
    console.log('running');

    var url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com/"

    // Get KW & category for search
    chrome.storage.local.get(["kw"],
        function (data) {
            kw = data.kw;

            console.log("redirecting to find kw: " + kw);

            // Send current tab to url
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: url});

                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: 'DOM_request'}, searchDOM);
            });
        }
    );
}

function searchDOM(domContent) {
    console.log("beginning dom search \n" + domContent);
}
```

**content_scripts/content_script.js**

```js
// Listen for messages
console.log("hello world")
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    // If the received message has the expected format...
    if (msg.type === 'DOM_request') {
        // Call the specified callback, passing
        // the web-page's DOM content as argument
        sendResponse(document.all[0].outerHTML);
    }
});
```

**console**

```js
running
redirecting to find kw: TestKeyword
beginning dom search 
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `onMessageExternal` is the wrong event (it's for [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external)):
you should use the standard `onMessage`.

Second, chrome extensions API is asynchronous so it only registers a job, returns immediately to continue to the next statement in your code without waiting for the job to complete:

1. chrome.tabs.update enqueues a navigation to a new URL
2. chrome.tabs.sendMessage enqueues a message sending job
3. the current page context in the tab gets destroyed along with the running content scripts
4. the tab starts loading the new URL
5. the message is delivered into the tab but there are no listeners,
   but this step may instead run right after step 2 depending on various factors so the content script running in the old page will receive it which is not what you want
6. the tab loads the served HTML and emits a `DOMContentLoaded` event
7. your content scripts run shortly after that because of the default ["run_at": "document_idle"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time)

---

There are at least three methods to properly time it all:

- make your content script emit a message and add an onMessage listener in the popup
- use chrome.tabs.onUpdated to wait for the tab to load
- use chrome.tabs.onUpdated + chrome.tabs.executeScript to simplify the entire thing

#### Let's take the executeScript approach.

1. remove `"content_scripts"` from manifest.json
2. instead of chrome.tabs.query (it's not needed) use the following:

   ```js
   chrome.tabs.update({url}, tab => {
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function onUpdated(tabId, change, updatedTab) {
       if (tabId === tab.id && change.status === 'complete') {
         chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
         chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
           code: 'document.documentElement.innerHTML',
         }, results => {
           searchDOM(results[0]);
         });
       }
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this all day and your solution worked! I'm a bit lost on the solution but I'll look more into the docs. Also, about messageExternal, that was an attempt to solve the issue that I forgot to correct before posting. I took the solution from your answer to another post, so was hoping you'd see this question and respond.

Comment: I've gone over your solution more and understand it more clearly now. If I wanted to extend this solution to now have the script return a certain link or a-tag in the website which contains the keyword, would I have to use method #1 you listed?

Comment: This will work, simply make sure the `code` string (or `file` parameter) ends up as a simple expression so it'll be picked up by executeScript, [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39806930), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42273774), and so on.